# Updating postgresql database: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL

Tags: java, postgresql, post

While trying to update a database parameters using a HTTP POST request I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: 
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at istsos.IstSOS.ExecuteRequest(IstSOS.java:210)
    at istsos.Database.setDatabase(Database.java:77)
    at istsos.Database.main(Database.java:105)
```

I removed the URL.

In any case, I checked with the REST responses and it works fine while in the application.

In the IstSOS class, the ExecuteRequest method it seems to have an issue with getting the response:

```
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);          
        httpCon.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postDataBytes);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));

        //assigning response to JSON
        String inputLine;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            //System.out.println(inputLine);
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(inputLine);
```

Basically in the end, I am returning a JSONObject using JSON in Java library for parsing the response.

So far, I've tried using try/catch and sort of System.out.print to see what's wrong but this time I can't really see what's going on.

Also, this sort of request is possible, the server doesn't restrict it as far as I know.

Comment: Evidently this sort of request isn't possible.  The HTTP 405 error says that the URL you are sending the POST request to does not support POST requests.

Comment: Error codes are useful; don't ignore the information that they provide. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes#405

Comment: @LukeWoodward Those were my initial thoughts, I'm a bit unclear about it. I've sent a question to the developers, I believe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Nicarus Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the issue. It was quite obvious, plain obvious that I couldn't update the DB through this method...